# How to install Joomla 3.x in silent mode

Tags: joomla, installation

Installing joomla via web is working fine. but I want it to happen via CLI or silent mode.
I tried the below steps to install joomla.
httpd, php, mysql installed in my linux machine.

1. Downloaded latest joomla tar and extracted in /var/www/html
2. Created database named as joomla in mysql
3. Copied configuration.php file and made necessary changes and put it in /var/www/html/configuration.php
4. restarted the server.

Try to open my website in browser but no luck. It was taking me to Joomla installation done page. while clicking site or administrator button in that page, nothing is happening.

Please help me to achieve silent mode installation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the installation is checking if you have config.php, which is supposed to do not exists when you want to install Joomla.

So you have just to remove | rename your config.php